# Find maximum number for a field in an array of students

Tags: c

I want to find the maximum number among the students, the data already given using pointer and structure of ten student.

My program gives the incorrect answer.

I am beginner in programming, can someone please tell me what is wrong with this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int rollno;
    int DS_marks;
    int machine_marks;
    int ADE_marks;
    int signal_system_marks;
    int math_marks;
};

int main()
{
    int SIZE;

    struct student st[] = {
        { 'ali', 3, 89, 76, 65, 45, 90},
        { 'ma', 9, 87, 67, 90, 54, 45},
        { 'la', 6, 78, 65, 43, 29, 342}
    };

    // student structure pointer variable
    struct student *ptr;
    ptr = &st;
    SIZE = sizeof(st) / 34;
    if (SIZE == 0)
    {
        printf("there is no student record");
    }
    else
    {
        int max = maximum(ptr, SIZE);
        printf("%d", max);
    }
    return 0;
}

int maximum(struct student *ptr, int SIZE)
{
    int b, i;

    printf("press number for subject\n ");
    printf("press 1 for DS:\n ");
    printf("press 2 for machine:\n ");
    printf("press 3 for ADE:\n ");
    printf("press 4 for signal system:\n ");
    printf("press 5 for math:\n ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    switch (b)
    {
        int maximum = 0;
        case 1:
        {
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if ((*ptr).DS_marks > maximum)
                {
                    maximum = (*ptr).DS_marks;
                }
                ++ptr;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if ((*ptr).DS_marks > maximum)
                {
                    maximum =(*ptr).machine_marks;
                }
                ++ptr;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if ((*ptr).ADE_marks > maximum)
                {
                    maximum =(*ptr).ADE_marks;
                }
                ++ptr;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if ((*ptr).signal_system_marks > maximum)
                {
                    maximum =(*ptr).signal_system_marks;
                }
                ++ptr;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                if ((*ptr).math_marks > maximum)
                {
                    maximum =(*ptr).math_marks;
                }
                ++ptr;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("you have pressed wrong number");
            break;
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You compute the number of items in `st` with `SIZE = sizeof(st) / 34;`. This is incorrect because the size of `struct student` is very unlikely to be `34`: there is most probably some padding between the `name` and `rollno` members to ensure proper alignement of the `int` members. You should not rely on hand computed *magical* values like that, simply use `SIZE = sizeof(st) / sizeof(st[0]);`, which works for all array types.
- function `maximum` should be declared or defined before use.
- you should check the return value of `scanf("%d", &b);` to avoid undefined behavior for invalid input: `scanf()` will return `EOF` if the input stream is empty and `0` if it cannot convert a number from the stream contents, leaving `b` unmodified and therefore uninitialized.
- initializing a local variable in the `switch` block as `int maximum = 0;` has no effect. The initialization code is bypassed as `switch` branches directly to the appropriate `case`.  This is the major error causing your problem, it is quite subtile and configuring the compiler to warn about such problems is wise. Use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Wall -Wextra -Werror` to avoid silly mistakes. Move the definition and initialization outside the `switch` statement.
- you assume that all fields positive values. This might cause problems if you apply the same algorithm for a member where all values would be negative. Initalizing `maximum` to the value of the first field instead of `0` solves this.
- in `case 2` you test the wrong member: `if ((*ptr).DS_marks > maximum)` instead of `if ((*ptr).machine_marks > maximum)`. A classic case of cut / paste / modify bug. Writing the test with `<` would help avoid such mistakes as the field member appears in the same position on the line: the eye would catch the lack of symmetry immediately. As a matter of fact, I only caught this error after rewriting the code for readability (see below).
- output should be terminated with newline: `printf("%d\n", max);` etc.
- not an error, but `(*ptr).DS_marks` is written much more readably as `ptr->DS_marks`.
- not an error, but all uppercase identifiers such as `SIZE` should be reserved for macros and predefined constants. In this case, `count` seems a better choice.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char name[10];
    int rollno;
    int DS_marks;
    int machine_marks;
    int ADE_marks;
    int signal_system_marks;
    int math_marks;
};

int maximum(const struct student *ptr, int count);

int main() {
    struct student st[] = {
        { 'ali', 3, 89, 76, 65, 45, 90 },
        { 'ma', 9, 87, 67, 90, 54, 45 },
        { 'la', 6, 78, 65, 43, 29, 342 },
    };
    int max = maximum(&st, sizeof(st) / sizeof(st[0]));

    if (max >= 0) {
        printf("%d\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}

int maximum(const struct student *ptr, int count) {
    int b, i, maximum;

    if (count <= 0) {
        printf("there are no student records\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("enter number for subject\n");
    printf("  enter 1 for DS:\n");
    printf("  enter 2 for machine:\n");
    printf("  enter 3 for ADE:\n");
    printf("  enter 4 for signal system:\n");
    printf("  enter 5 for math:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &b) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return -1;
    }

    switch (b) {
        case 1: {
            maximum = ptr[0].DS_marks;
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                if (maximum < ptr[i].DS_marks) {
                    maximum = ptr[i].DS_marks;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            maximum = ptr[0].machine_marks;
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                if (maximum < ptr[i].machine_marks) {
                    maximum = ptr[i].machine_marks;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            maximum = ptr[0].ADE_marks;
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                if (maximum < ptr[i].ADE_marks) {
                    maximum = ptr[i].ADE_marks;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            maximum = ptr[0].signal_system_marks;
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                if (maximum < ptr[i].signal_system_marks) {
                    maximum = ptr[i].signal_system_marks;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            maximum = ptr[0].math_marks;
            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                if (maximum < ptr[i].math_marks) {
                    maximum = ptr[i].math_marks;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            printf("you have entered an invalid number\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```